# Excluir números en una fuente usando unicode-range

Tags: css, css3

He estado buscando como excluir/eliminar los números de una fuente predeterminada que uso en un sitio web y que los reemplace por "system-ui". Lo único que encontré es que solo incluya los números y excluya las letras usando **unicode-range** de la siguiente manera `unicode-range: U+0030-0039`.

Existe una expresión para excluir?

Comment: puedes editar la fuente y quitarle los números usando esta herramienta https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Excelente la herramienta. Muchas gracias! Si la respondes como solución te la confirmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes editar la fuente y quitarle los números usando esta herramienta fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator